# Extremum of the functional $f(x+g(x))$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

As the title states I would like to find a $g(x)$ such that $f(x+g(x))|_{x=a}$ is maximum/minimum where $f(x)$ is known.

I have looked at Euler-Lagrange equations but they are derived for integral functionals and I am not sure whether it is applicable in my case. (I am also not sure whether such $g(x)$ exists.) Can you please state a solution or provide references for the solution?

I would like to generalize my solution to n dimensional space, thus a solution in one dimensional is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Suppose that $x^*$ is a maximiser. Then define $g(x) = x^*-a$.

Comment: @mlc, if $g(x)=x^*−a$ then, $g(x)$ is not a function of $x$. Do you mean $g(x)=x-a$? If that is the case, what is your derivation?

Comment: it is a (constant) function. But perhaps I missing some facet of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question suggests that you're trying to find $g(x)$ for which $f(x+g(x))|_{x=a}$ is extremal , so you're trying to find extremum in $x=a$ .

In that case you can just differentiate : 
$\frac{d}{dx}f(x+g(x))=0 \implies f'(a+g(a))(1+g'(a))=0$.
This doesn't give you a requirement for a function $g()$ but rather two numbers : $g(a)$ and $g'(a)$.
You can choose $g()$ such that $a+g(a)$ gives a zero value for $f'()$, or such that $g'(a)=-1$.
So it only gives you a requirement for $g()$ and / or $g'()$ in point $a$. Rest is free to choose.

PS : Euler-Lagrange and variational calculus are usually used to find extremum of an integral e.g. : 
$\int_{a}^{b} f(x+g(x)) dx $ . 
In such cases the outcome will be a differential equation with which you can find functions $g()$ that give extrema for the integral.
From the above you can see why this is not applicable or necessary in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but something seems to be missing. First of all assume that $f′(a+g(a))≠0$. That means $g′(x)_{x=a}=−1→g′(x)_{x=a}=−1$. But what should $g(a)$ be? Thing about like this, I am at point $a$ and would like to go to point $a+g^*(a)$ such that among all $g(x)$s $f(a+g^*(a))$ is maximum.

Comment: about naming no problem.(I am adding your name as @rutger-moody but the comment does not show.) About the comment, thank you but I did not understand it. Can you please explain more? Also if we can not find an exact $g(x)$ is it possible to find the sign of $g(x)$ ?, e.g. $g(x)>0$ or $g(x)<0$ ?

Comment: thanks for the comment. may be I should post a new question. Actually I would like to find out $g(x)$ to be $g(x)=f'(x)$.  (A kind of proof that the gradient gives the maximum increase in the function.) But it seems that we could not get that result. Thanks again.